# Overflow Hidden Not working - tried to put overflow hidden in container but it cuts the picture

Tags: html, css, overflow

I was following a tutorial but it doesn't give the same output.
Please help me.
I tried the solution that was asked here but it cuts the picture.

CSS:

```
#mainSlider{
            width: 960px;
            height:500px;
            display: block;
            position:relative;
            margin:auto;

        }
        #Islider{
            width:960px;
            height:500px;
            display:block;
            position:absolute;
             overflow:hidden;
        }
        .info{
            width:960px;
            height:80px;
            display:block;
            position:relative;
            background: rgb(120, 217, 132);
            z-index:99;
            bottom: 100px;

        }

        .info h2{
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color:#FFF;
            padding: 15px 0 0 20px;


        }
        .info p{
            font-family:sans-serif;
            font-size:15px;
            font-weight: lighter;
            color:#FFF;
            padding:0 0 0 20px;
            line-height: 1px;

        }
        #play{
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            line-height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            background: rgb(0, 255, 144);
            color: #FFF;
            cursor:pointer;
            z-index: 999;
            top: 0;
            right: 44px;
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);

        }
         #pause{
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            line-height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            background: rgb(0, 255, 144);
            color: #FFF;
            cursor:pointer;
            z-index: 999;
            top: 0;
            right: 88px;
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
          #next{
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            line-height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            background: rgb(0, 255, 144);
            color: #FFF;
            cursor:pointer;
            z-index: 999;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
           #previous{
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            line-height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            background: rgb(0, 255, 144);
            color: #FFF;
            cursor:pointer;
            z-index: 999;
            top: 0;
            right: 133px;
        }

           #pager{
               width:100px;
               text-align:center;
               display:block;
               position:absolute;
               cursor:pointer;
               z-index:999;

           }
           #pager a{
               width: 10px;
               height: 10px;
               display:inline-block;
               position:relative;
               border: 1px solid #FFF;
               border-radius:20px;
               background: #FFF;

           }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mainSlider">

             <div id="pager"></div>
             <div id="pause">&asymp;</div>
             <div id="play">&Delta;</div>
             <div id="next">&raquo;</div>
             <div id="previous">&laquo;</div>


            <div id="iSlider">

                <div class="items">

                <img src="images/p1.jpg" />

                    <div class="info">

                    <h2>Title </h2>
                    <p> Some paragraph <a href="www.fb.com"> Title </a> </p>

                    </div>

                </div>

                 <div class="items">

                <img src="images/p2.jpg" />

                    <div class="info">

                    <h2>Title </h2>
                    <p> Some paragraph <a href="www.fb.com"> Title </a> </p>

                    </div>

                </div>

                 <div class="items">

                <img src="images/p3.jpg" />

                    <div class="info">

                    <h2>Title </h2>
                    <p> Some paragraph <a href="www.fb.com"> Title </a> </p>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

      </div>
```

Here is the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vaughnellis/xomcshz4/
I already tried the solution here which is to put the overflow hidden in the container which is Islider but it doesn't work. I also tried to put it in #mainSlider but it cuts the picture in half.
Please help.
Thank you!

Comment: thats the point of `overflow:hidden;` ... to cut everything that is overflowing

Comment: It would be interesting to see the tutorial, just to know how it is supposed to look like

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0iP8YwTo7To this is the link of the tutorial. there should be only one image showing. it shouldn't cut the picture. just hide am i right?

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to hide scroll, apply the "overflow: hidden;" to body not
   to `<div>` containers.
2. For the cut image please delete "bottom: 100px;" from ".info".

```css
body {overflow: hidden;}        

#mainSlider{
        width: 960px;
        height:500px;
        display: block;
        position:relative;
        margin:auto;

    }
    #Islider{
        width:960px;
        height:500px;
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
         overflow:hidden;
    }
    .info{
        width:960px;
        height:80px;
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        background: rgb(120, 217, 132);
        z-index:99;


    }

    .info h2{
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color:#FFF;
        padding: 15px 0 0 20px;


    }
    .info p{
        font-family:sans-serif;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight: lighter;
        color:#FFF;
        padding:0 0 0 20px;
        line-height: 1px;

    }
    #play{
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background: rgb(0, 255, 144);
        color: #FFF;
        cursor:pointer;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 0;
        right: 44px;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);

    }
     #pause{
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background: rgb(0, 255, 144);
        color: #FFF;
        cursor:pointer;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 0;
        right: 88px;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
      #next{
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background: rgb(0, 255, 144);
        color: #FFF;
        cursor:pointer;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
       #previous{
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background: rgb(0, 255, 144);
        color: #FFF;
        cursor:pointer;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 0;
        right: 133px;
    }

       #pager{
           width:100px;
           text-align:center;
           display:block;
           position:absolute;
           cursor:pointer;
           z-index:999;

       }
       #pager a{
           width: 10px;
           height: 10px;
           display:inline-block;
           position:relative;
           border: 1px solid #FFF;
           border-radius:20px;
           background: #FFF;

       }
```

here is my demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xomcshz4/1)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for helping me out. but on the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0iP8YwTo7To it should just show one picture. please help me. im still learning